# I need help understanding a simple proof about determinants of matrices.

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

[image]

**What I don't understand:**

I don't understand why in the proof

det(**Q**) = $λa_{i1}C_{i1}$(**A**) + $λa_{i2}C_{i2}$(**A**) + ... + $λa_{in}C_{in}$(**A**).

Shouldn't the det(**Q**) = $λa_{i1}C_{i1}$(**Q**) + $λa_{i2}C_{i2}$(**Q**) + ... + $λa_{in}C_{in}$(**Q**)?

Comment: Well, $C_{i1}(A) $ is same as $C_{i1}(Q) $.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thanks for your help, I understand now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is evaluated according to the $i$th row and so the equation in the proof is correct.